# Использовать сразу несколько версий PHP

Tags: php, apache, path

Я работаю на двух проектах, у одного версия php 5.6, у другого 7.2
Когда прихожу с одного проекта на другой,каждый раз меняю версию здесь.
[image: переменная среды]

И в OpenServer.

[image: замена версии в OpenServer]

Вопрос,как использовать сразу две версии,каждый раз не изменяя ничего в системе?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте docker, по другому никак.

Comment: буду попробовать,спасибо

Comment: Никак - это очень сильно сказано)

Answer (score 1):

Laragon позволяет переключать версию php в 2 клика.

Аналогичные возможности есть в Local Lightning by Flywheel.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx, а также Apache, вполне себе позволяет использовать любую версию PHP для сайта. Смотрите [Как мне создать собственную конфигурацию хоста для домена?](https://ospanel.io/docs/#voprosy-i-otvety). Создаёте конфигурацию и в ней проставляете какой PHP использовать и откуда.

Единственный момент состоит в том что тогда в настройках OSPanel вы не сможете настраивать оба, а только один, так как там подразумевается что вы должны использовать одну версию для всех сайтов.